# How to group the the columns of dataframe to list in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
   member_srl  click_day  productid
0        6963   20170106    3927352
1        6963   20170106    3790726
2        6963   20170106     977962
3        6963   20170106    1393860
4        6963   20170106    3759353
```

Here is my df and I want to group the member_srl and click_day, to get the list of productid. For example, member_srl 6963 and click_day 20170106 will correspond to the product list: [3927352,3790726,977962,1393860,3759353]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `list`:

```
df = df.groupby(['member_srl','click_day'])['productid'].apply(list)
print (df)
member_srl  click_day
6963        20170106     [3927352, 3790726, 977962, 1393860, 3759353]
Name: productid, dtype: object

df = df.groupby(['member_srl','click_day'])['productid'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
   member_srl  click_day                                     productid
0        6963   20170106  [3927352, 3790726, 977962, 1393860, 3759353]
```

Comment: Well , It seems that I should enlarge my memory(16G) while the original csv is 16G. It crashed when I use your codes. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion 16GB RAM is problematic if use 16GB csv. :( Is possible add RAM or use another machine?

Comment: Thanks. I am move data to another machine. Thanks a lot.